# Add extra field to queryset serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a list API view:

```
class ListRequisitesOfEnrollee(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RequisiteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        enrollee = Enrollee.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        requisites = enrollee.requisites.all()
        if isinstance(enrollee, OrganisationUnit):
            requisites = requisites | enrollee.org.requisites.all()
        elif isinstance(enrollee, ElsUser):
            org_unit_requisites = enrollee.organisation_unit.requisites.all()
            org_requisites = enrollee.organisation_unit.org.requisites.all()
            groups = Enrollee.objects.filter(group__users=enrollee)
            for group in groups:
                requisites = requisites | group.requisites.all()
            requisites = requisites | org_unit_requisites | org_requisites

        return requisites
```

I want to add an extra "`source`" field to the queryset on specific objects
For example , inside

```
isinstance(enrollee, OrganisationUnit) , 
requisites = requisites + enrollee.org.requisites.all()
```

The `enrollee.org.requisites.all() queryset` must contain an extra field `source ="Org Name"`.

I want to avoid adding any extra fields to Table

Answer (score 0):

you can use the extra method for that

```
enrollee.org.requisites.extra(
    select={
        'source': "name"=> it can be replace by query also
    },
)
```

Comment: after adding this will serializer show the extra field

Comment: uou need to add in the serializer fields

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "619a985c"

Comment: i want to get enrollee.org.name inside source

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "Default": syntax error  when i tried:

Comment: requisites = requisites | enrollee.org.requisites.extra(
                select={
                    'source_name': enrollee.org.name,
            }).all()